# New component not rendering Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I am a beginner in Angular. I would like to create a new component in my project but it's not rendering when i use it in my index.html.

I used this command:

```
ng new test
cd test
ng generate component radio
```

and after i edited my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  <app-radio>Loading...</app-radio>
</body>
</html>
```

The result when i did `ng serve`:

```
 app works!
 Loading...
```

In app/radio/radio.component.html i have this code auto-generated:

```
<p>
  radio works!
</p>
```

So, why  it's not rendering in my browser ? Where is my error ?

Comment: Please check Javascript console for possible exceptions.

Comment: I have in my Javascript console this error : `[WDS] Disconnected! 
vendor.bundle.js:61252:10`

Comment: Stop the application by running “ctrl + c” command. Run “ng lint” to see possible build errors. Seems to be a problem with cli bundling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app-root is the application container for your angular app.

Set your `<app-radio></app-radio>` inside the app.component.html and you should see it.

Hope that helps !

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned *@Florian Bastianelli*

`<app-root></app-root>` is the angular container so you need to place `<app-radio></app-radio>` inside the main module.